# Add a prefix to a bunch of urls

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.2

I have a bunch of routes with the same prefix:

```
# with prefixes
GET         /api/v1.0/action1   controllers.Api.action1
GET         /api/v1.0/action2   controllers.Api.action2
GET         /api/v1.0/action3   controllers.Api.action3
GET         /api/v1.0/action4   controllers.Api.action4

# normal urls
GET         /action1   controllers.Home.action1
GET         /action2   controllers.Home.action2
```

I want to get rid of repetition of `/api/v1.0/`. The urls must remain the same, I just want to not write them manually for each url in `route` file. In Rails it's possible. If there any way to do that?

Comment: If you have such trivial example, try: `GET         /api/v1.0/:action   controllers.Api.action(action:String)` and dispatch in controller: `def action(action:String)  = Action { def method:java.lang.reflection.Method = getMethodFromNameOrMap(action); method.invoke()}`

Comment: @ajozwik, it would be slow due to reflection

Comment: if you use cached map (map action name to method) - it will be two time slower than normal call. But the cost is with every implementation of JVM lower.

Comment: Sorry for not giving you a complete answer, but have you looked at James Roper's [blog post on advanced routing](http://jazzy.id.au/default/2013/05/08/advanced_routing_in_play_framework.html). Basically you can write routing in Scala which means you have the full power of a programming language to avoid repeating yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Either you implement your own router for these actions following [James Ropers' post](http://jazzy.id.au/default/2013/05/08/advanced_routing_in_play_framework.html), as mentioned by Rich. Doing so, allows you add the following to your route file:

```
->  /api/v1.0   YourPathBindableController
```

Alternatively you can use a plugin, such as [navigator](https://github.com/teamon/play-navigator), which offers you advanced routing. Your navigator route file would then contain something like:

```
   // Namespace ...
namespace("api"){
  namespace("v1"){
    GET on "index" to Application.index _
  }
}

// ... or with reverse routing support
val api = new Namespace("api"){
  val v2 = new Namespace("v2"){
    val about = GET on "about" to Application.about _
  }
}
```